# development environment for python projects

Tags: python, ide, text-editor

I am running python on linux and am currently using vim for my single-file programs, and gedit for multi-file programs. I have seen development environments like eclipse and was basically wondering if there's a similar thing on ubuntu designed for python.

Comment: Eclipse + PyDev works on Ubuntu too, if memory serves...

Comment: You are on the edge of a non-constructive, and off-topic question here. Good thing you left out asking for opinions or 'the best'.

Comment: Komodo, PyCharm, Eclipse + PyDev, Sublime Text 2 all should work on Ubuntu.

Comment: did you even searched for `eclipse` on ubuntu software center?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I thought the same thing until I actually read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  "But if your question covers ... software tools commonly used by programmers ... then you're in the right place to ask your question".  But I suppose since it's not a "specific tool", then it is likely to solicit debate/polling, etc.

Comment: @mgilson: Yeah, but this isn't necessarily a practical problem with a software tool. It's still a shopping list recommendation, albeit one that's a little more focused than most.

Comment: [What IDE to use for Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/81584/558094)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question!

Personally I only use VIM, however, there are 2 great IDEs I can think of for Python development on Ubuntu (and many other Linux distros) one of which is Eclipse.

(1) So, Eclipse has a development suite plug-in for Python called PyDev. To get Eclipse on an Ubuntu machine you should just be able to type:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

into a terminal, or use the software center. Once you have Eclipse, you will need to add the PyDev addon. This [tutorial](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) can help you with that, but basically all it consists of is entering the "Install new Software" menu and then linking the PyDev repo.

(2) Another great option is to use MonoDevelop! Monodev has a Python development suite that can be downloaded simply by entering

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop-python
```

I would suggest trying both of these out to find which best suites your needs and wants as a Python developer.

For more information on these IDEs and more, here's a great [comprehensive, comparative list of IDEs with Python support](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments).

Answer (score 2):

There is Eclipse version for Python called [PyDev](http://pydev.org/). For a full list of Python IDE please consult [this page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments).

Answer (score 0):

Komodo is a good commercial IDE.And Eric is a free python IDE which is written with python.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Python, [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is a great choice.  There's also [Intellij IDEA Ultimate](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), which has an equivalent level of Python support to PyCharm (but is more costly).  Both make use of Java, so it runs on any platform with Java on it.